# How does struct implemet Equals

Tags: c#, class, struct

I have a struct

```
public struct item
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

If I create a `HashSet<item>` and add two equal items, the second doesn't insert because it already exists (equals seems to throw the same value)

```
HashSet<item> hsi = new HashSet<item>();
Console.WriteLine(hsi.Add(new item() { id = 1, name = "test" })); //true
Console.WriteLine(hsi.Add(new item() { id = 1, name = "test" })); //false - expected result
```

now If I change the `struct` to `class`

```
public class item //changed struct to class
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

the result is

```
HashSet<item> hsi = new HashSet<item>();
Console.WriteLine(hsi.Add(new item() { id = 1, name = "test" })); //true
Console.WriteLine(hsi.Add(new item() { id = 1, name = "test" })); //true
```

question: why does equals work for struct but not for class?

Comment: All structs are derived from `System.ValueType` and use its implementation of `Equals` and `GetHashCode`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For structs (value types), `Equals` compares the whole value of the struct, meaning all fields.

The default implementation of `object.Equals()` (for classes) does a **reference** comparison. It compares if two references "point" to the same instance of a class, but doesn't compare the *content* of the instances.

---

> so the struct comparison doesn't work if one of the properties is a object e.g. `List<int>`?

It does "work", but maybe not the way you expect it to. It won't compare the *content* of the lists, it only checks if the properties reference the same list instance.
If you want to compare them deeply, you need to override `Equals` and implement it yourself.

But note that it works with `string`, because when comparing the properties, the `Equals` method of these properties is called, and `string.Equals()` is overridden to compare the string content.

Comment: You may note, that struct are using reflection to check for equality, so if you know you will have multiple comparisons, you may overwrite `Equals`

Comment: so the `struct` comparison doesn't work if one of the properties is a `object` e.g. `List<int>`?

Comment: @Toshi it does "work", but maybe not the way you expect it to. It won't compare the _content_ of the lists, it only checks if the properties reference the same list instance. If you want to compare them deeply, you need to override `Equals` and implement it yourself.

Comment: @Toshi but note that it works with `string`, because when comparing the properties, the `Equals` method of these properties is called, and `string.Equals()` is overridden to compare the string content.